# How to get Unique Display name for VSTS/TFS identity?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, tfs, azure-devops

I am a writing a .Net application using the [VSTS/TFS Rest .Net libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts) and in one place I need to update workitems' System.AssignedTo field values and while I do want to adhere to the [new(ish), unique displayname rules](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/01/13/identities-and-work-item-tracking-in-tfs-2015/) for identity work item fields, I have a hard time finding a method to get the Unique display name(s) for given identities.

The old / client object model [does have an explicit helper method](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/01/13/identities-and-work-item-tracking-in-tfs-2015/) to get these unique names, but I have not found any rest endpoint nor client api method that would provide the same.

So I am wondering, given a list of identities, how do I get their corresponding unique display names which I can use to unambiguously set identity work item fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            String collectionUri = "http://collectionurl/";
            VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
            creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), creds);
            TeamHttpClient thc = connection.GetClient<TeamHttpClient>();
            List<IdentityRef> irs = thc.GetTeamMembersAsync("ProjectName","TeamName").Result;
            foreach (IdentityRef ir in irs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ir.UniqueName);
                Console.WriteLine(ir.DisplayName);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie! I had used that but didn't find it quite efficient to iterate over all teams in order to get all or one specific identity in a given team project. But technically it works so it's good enough. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below to get unique name:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;

namespace ConsoleApplication3

{

    class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            TfsConfigurationServer tcs = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs"));

            IIdentityManagementService ims = tcs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

            TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\\Team Foundation Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            TeamFoundationIdentity[] ids = ims.ReadIdentities(tfi.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity id in ids)

            {
                if (id.Descriptor.IdentityType == "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity")

                {
                    Console.WriteLine(id.DisplayName);
                    Console.WriteLine(id.UniqueName);
                }

            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good evening & thanks - but that code example is using the old, Client Object Model apparently. As mentioned above, I am using the new REST based .Net client libraries only and was wondering how to do it with those.

Comment: @JörgB. Do you use VSTS or on-premise TFS?  If you use VSTS, there are [Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/account/accounts/list) and [Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/profile/profiles/get) REST api available to get profiles. If you use on-premise TFS, check following rest api `http://server:8080/tfs/_api/_common/GetUserProfile?__v=5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var workItem in workItems)
{
     if (workItem.Fields.ContainsKey("System.AssignedTo"))
     {
         var person = (IdentityRef)workItem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"];
         string codereview_reviewer = person.DisplayName;
          Console.WriteLine(codereview_reviewer);
     }
}
```