# How to use TfsTeamProjectCollection in TFS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs

I am trying to get an email address from an IdentityRef.

```
IdentityRef test = (IdentityRef)workItem.Fields["System.CreatedBy"];
var test2 = test.UniqueName;
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri, credentials);
tfs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService2>();
var test3 = identityService.ReadIdentity(test2);
```

This code gives me "CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TfsTeamProjectCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have tried a variety of "using" directives to get TfsTeamProjectCollection to recognize:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
```

All of these give me some combination of "IDE0005: Using directive is unnecessary", "CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Foo' does not exist in the namespace 'Bar'", "CS0103: The name 'Foo' does not exist in the current context".

I have Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client, Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient installed

Comment: What version of TFS? The client libraries you're trying to use are very old and have largely been deprecated in favor of REST APIs. If you're using any version of TFS after 2015, look at the REST API options available instead.

Comment: Do you know how to query the REST API from C#?

Comment: There are REST API client libraries or you can just use `HttpClient`. Start by reviewing the REST API documentation. Note that the REST APIs may not be available or only a subset of functionality may be available depending on the version of TFS you're using. You've tagged your question with both Azure DevOps and TFS, so you need to provide more context on what version you're using or whether you're using Azure DevOps in the cloud.

Comment: Make sure you're building a .NET 4 app. These APIs leverage SOAP and WCF and are likely not available on .NET 5+ and .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

I was Facing the same issue. Even though installed the package of Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Client dll's for the same wasn't there in bin folder.

So make sure dll of Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Client is there in bin folder if not try to paste the dll of Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Client there.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you TFS **Uri** and **Credentials** are correct.

You are using an old version of libraires & packages that are no longer supported.

If you are using a before 2015 TFS or above, you need to update the relevant package as latest.

Below 2015 TFS version follow the below steps:

Install packages with latest versions and check steps [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/connect-to-tfs-using-c-sharp)

Refer TFS 2015 above  check here [Link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) & [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948594/how-to-get-unique-display-name-for-vsts-tfs-identity)